# Subsections of binary necklaces

Tags: combinatorics

Say we have a binary necklace (a string of 0's and 1's arranged in a circle) with $a$ 0's and $b$ 1's.  We can define a function $f(n,k)$ as the number of segments of the necklace of length $n$ having exactly $k$ ones.

My problem is what exactly are the restrictions on $f$, i.e. if you give me an $f$ how can I recognize that it came from a binary necklace?  There are some obvious restrictions, $\sum_{k=1}^n k f(n,k) = nb$ as each one is counted exactly $n$ times, and $f(n,k) = f(a+b-n, b-k)$ as every one is ether in a segment or not.  Also $\sum_{k>j}f(n,k) > \sum_{k>j}f(n+1,k)$.

Are there simple necessary and sufficient conditions on $f$ extending the ones above?  The problem of uniqueness and reconstruction of the necklace are interesting, but all I want is a way of recognizing $f$.

I'm probably missing something obvious.  I'm pretty sure that this has been looked at before.